# How to select all pre elements inside of class, recursively?

Tags: html, css

I have a very small project (html + css), where all of the "pre" tags had a CSS style. It was looking like this:

```
pre { color: blue; }
```

But now, I want to add this into a very large project, and I don't want to ruin everything. I want to modify only those "pre" tags, which are related to this specific small thing. So my idea is, that I will put everything - which is related to this - in the inside of a wrapper "div" element, and only those "pre" tags should be affected with the CSS which are in the inside of this wrapper, no matter how deep.

An example:

```
<pre> not this </pre>
<div> not this </div>
<pre> also not this one </pre>
<div class="wrapper">
  <pre> this should be affected </pre>
  <pre> this should be affected </pre>
  <pre> this should be affected </pre>
  <div>
    <h1>
      <span>
          <pre> This should be also affected, but it is sadly not working. </pre>
      </span>
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my CSS, but this is only working for the top-level "pre" tags:

```
.wrapper pre {
    color: blue;
}
```

If I modify the CSS to this:

```
pre {
    color: blue;
}
```

That will work for all of the "pre" elements, but the problem is, I want it only for those "pre" elements which are in the inside of the wrapper element.

How can I solve this? I was reading stackoverflow and other sites about CSS, and I am trying to solve this but I cannot figure this out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided already works. Do you have more CSS rules in your other project that are maybe preventing your inner `pre`s to not become blue?

```css
.wrapper pre {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<pre> not this </pre>
<div> not this </div>
<pre> also not this one </pre>
<div class="wrapper">
  <pre> this should be affected </pre>
  <pre> this should be affected </pre>
  <pre> this should be affected </pre>
  <div>
    <h1>
      <span>
          <pre>This should be also affected, but it is sadly not working.</pre>
      </span>
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was trying this in w3school's "tryit editor", with different names (but the point was the same), and it was not working. Now I tried again and it is working. I don't understand, but thank you for your help.